# JMeter : Define Test Fragment Inputs

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I'm trying to define fragment inputs, which are variables that should be defined to have the fragment execute successfully (I'm trying to achieve something similar to method arguments in programming languages)

I have tried to use test plan variables in the fragment like so :
[image]

But when the fragment is included in another test plan and with looking to the Debug PostProcessor output, those variables are completely ignored.

Please is there official JMeter documentation that mention test plan variables are ignored in this case ?
What is the cleanest way to define variables for a fragment with a scope local to the fragment or at least local to current thread ? My purpose to make a fragment clearly defined what are the variable it uses, so it can be easily reused by other developers
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you need to declare the variables to be used in the test fragment - go for [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables-Using-User-Defined-Variables) configuration element like:

[image]

When you call a Test Fragment from a separate [Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan) the variables defined in that Test Plan will be available for usage.

Alternative option is using JMeter Properties which are global for the whole JVM

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think  User Defined Variables are shared between all threads, so it won't solve the issue

Comment: I'm not telepathic enough to guess what "issue" you're trying to "solve", if you want to set specific values for each thread you can use [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and the code like `vars.put('foo', 'bar')` where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry If it was not clear enough. I wanted to know if there are best practices for defining clearly what variables are used by a test fragment (even if they are already available by the test plan in which it is included) to make it self documented for other developers

Comment: The [best documented practice](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller) is `If the test uses a Cookie Manager or User Defined Variables, these should be placed in the top-level test plan, not the included file, otherwise they are not guaranteed to work.` In general test fragment is designed for using with the [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) in order to avoid code duplication

Comment: @DmitriT  So it's possible to have User Defined Variables inside the Test Fragments as well as the Test Plan (containing all the Test Fragments) ?  Is that correct ?  I want to know the scope of the User Defined Variables.  Are they available throughout the Test Plan, regardless of where they are in the Test Fragment (local a global var) ?  If yes, what would happen if I have 2 User Defined Variables with the same name in the Test Fragment ? Or I should ensure they all don't have the same name ?  Thanks very much